# How to wait for a method to finish completely before proceeding?

Tags: java

the coding below will run OSK (On Screen Keyboard) process after killProcess() kills it, previously it does not pop up before I added the Thread.sleep for 1 second. So is there any way that I can make sure killProcess() is fully executed before it start the OSK process without Thread.sleep for one second?? something that is not timed-based, a code that will run killProcess() completely before going into the next line. Sorry for any confusion and thanks for reading! Hope someone is willing to help me with this one.

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    try {
        killProcess();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }

        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("c:\\Temp\\osk.exe");

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public static void killProcess() throws Exception {

    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();

    rt.exec("cmd.exe /c taskkill " + "osk.exe");

    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /IM " + "osk.exe");

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    try {
        killProcess();
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("c:\\Temp\\osk.exe");

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void killProcess() throws Exception {
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    rt.exec("cmd.exe /c taskkill " + "osk.exe").waitFor();
    rt.exec("taskkill /IM " + "osk.exe").waitFor();
}
```

[Runtime.exec(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29) returns a [Process](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html), which has the [waitFor()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor%28%29) method. This will block the current [Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) until the process has terminated.

Comment: I'm a bit unsure as to why you're running `taskkill` in two different ways. I don't even think that the first call will work, but I've focused on the Java aspects of this question, rather than the Windows Command Line aspects.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Both taskkill is working, it's just a little experiment that I did earlier to check whether does both of it is working or not

Comment: The first invocation didn't work for me in Windows 7 in the command line, but if it's working for you now, that's great. I'm glad I could help.